# Openshift 3.11 header based routing

Tags: haproxy, openshift-origin, okd

I'm trying to implement a header based routing on Openshift 3.11.

I mean, I want HAProxy to route requests to a certain service based on header presence and value rather than hostname. The header value would be set in the route configuration.

I know this is possible with HAProxy, but I don't know how to do this.
I followed a piece of advice I found [here](https://blog.openshift.com/ocp-custom-routing/) but it seems the configuration has changed and it doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestion would be welcome. I have an alternative, which would be to put a 2nd proxy that would do the work, but this would not be elegant at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to make it work properly. But it wasn't the documentation that helped.
The piece of code showed in the link I posted in the question is to put under the following configuration parts :

- `frontend public` (http proxy)
- `frontend fe_sni` (https proxy with custom certificates)
- `frontend fe_no_sni` (https proxy with default certificate)

Also, the piece of code was old and didn't contain the actual variable names.
Here is one that, for every route:

- looks for a route annotation named `haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id`
- create 2 acls checking for the value of a cookie named `tenant-id` and if the host is the expected one (the host value is configurable with the route annotation `haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-hostname`
- checks if the 2 acls return true and if so makes the http request to the service behind the route

```
  # Custom snippet for balancing through HTTP headers
  {{- range $cfgIdx, $cfg := .State }}
  {{- if (ne (index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id") "") }}
  acl custom_header_{{index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id"}} cook(tenant-id) {{index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id"}}
  acl configured_host_{{index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id"}} hdr(host) {{index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-hostname"}}
  use_backend be_edge_http:{{$cfgIdx}} if configured_host_{{index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id"}} custom_header_{{index $cfg.Annotations "haproxy.router.openshift.io/tenant-id"}}

  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```